# Customize ion-select icon in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-select

I am developing an application using Ionic 4 and I am using ion-select. I want to customize the select icon, but the style is not applied.

```
<ion-select interface="popover" 
    (ionChange)="onSelectionChanged()"
    [(ngModel)]="item.Value">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.Value">
        {{ option.Title }}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

This is the style written in the .scss file, but it is not applied. I've also checked the documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

```
.select-icon .select-icon-inner {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent !important;
    border-top: 7px solid !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the little arrow on the right, it seems that it is not possible at least fot the moment, see 
[issue here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17248)
You can use a button and a modal though.